# Windows 8 start screen tile, based on desktop shortcut

Tags: c#, windows-8, shortcut, windows-shell, tile

I have a currently working code *(C#, but not important)* that adds a tile to the **Windows 8** start screen by means of creating a shortcut file [`.lnk`] within special directories like `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Application Shortcuts`. I have searched for and found several useful tools like [`lnk-parser`](https://code.google.com/p/lnk-parser/) and [OblyTile](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1899865), which have helped in clearing several aspects about the quirks involved. I have also found many articles and questions related to the topic, but none quite exactly addresses my specific needs.

I'm using [`IShellLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774950.aspx) *(COM interop)* to create the shortcut and [`IPropertyStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761474.aspx) *(same object instance)* to add some apparently required properties to the link file. My specific problem and question are these:

The created tile works as expected in almost every aspect. It runs the intended command, has the intended background and foreground colors, and displays the custom associated icon *(*`.png` *image 144x144)*. The problem is that, even though it has a custom label string embedded in the link file [`System.ItemTypeText`], it just displays the name of the physical file minus the extension. That's not so horrible, but I would prefer that Windows honored the embedded property over the file name.

**What might be missing in the link file that causes such behavior and not the desired one?**

---

## Bonus

By using `IPropertyStore`, I have come across several so called "property sets", which are just properties grouped by their [`GUID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier). I have special interest in the sets <strike>`{b725f130-47ef-101a-a5f1-02608c9eebac}`</strike> `{86d40b4d-9069-443c-819a-2a54090dccec}` and `{9f4c2855-9f79-4b39-a8d0-e1d42de1d5f3}` (the latter contains the ubiquitous **`System.AppUserModel.ID`**).

Extra question: can you please point to any resource which documents any (or both) of these two property sets? I mean, what do each property mean and how are they interpreted by Windows. This might be even more helpful than the main question. No matter if it's official or unofficial.

## Note

Using `OblyTile` by calling it with a command line is not an option, as per requirements. According to what I've observed, I might need to add a custom `resources.pri` file in the link's target file parent directory. It would be desirable to avoid that, if at all possible, because the format is not documented.

## Sample code

The `ShellLink` class is a plain-old & boring wrapper around the `IShellLink` and `IPropertyStore` **COM** interfaces. It works just fine, I'm completely sure the problem is not there.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Shell32NET
{
    public static class Win8Tiles
    {
        #region Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// b725f130-47ef-101a-a5f102608c9eebac
        /// </summary>
        static readonly Guid ItemTypeGroup = new Guid(
            0xb725f130, 0x47ef, 0x101a, 0xa5, 0xf1, 0x02, 0x60, 0x8c, 0x9e, 0xeb, 0xac
            );

        /// <summary>
        /// b725f130-47ef-101a-a5f102608c9eebac, 4
        /// </summary>
        static readonly PropertyKey SystemItemTypeText = new PropertyKey(ItemTypeGroup, 4);

        /// <summary>
        /// 86d40b4d-9069-443c-819a2a54090dccec
        /// </summary>
        static readonly Guid TilePropertiesGroup = new Guid(
            0x86d40b4d, 0x9069, 0x443c, 0x81, 0x9a, 0x2a, 0x54, 0x09, 0x0d, 0xcc, 0xec
            );

        /// <summary>
        /// 86d40b4d-9069-443c-819a2a54090dccec, 2
        /// </summary>
        static readonly PropertyKey TileSmallImageLocation = new PropertyKey(TilePropertiesGroup, 2);

        /// <summary>
        /// 86d40b4d-9069-443c-819a2a54090dccec, 4
        /// </summary>
        static readonly PropertyKey TileBackgroundColor = new PropertyKey(TilePropertiesGroup, 4);

        /// <summary>
        /// 86d40b4d-9069-443c-819a2a54090dccec, 5
        /// </summary>
        static readonly PropertyKey TileForegroundColor = new PropertyKey(TilePropertiesGroup, 5);

        /// <summary>
        /// 86d40b4d-9069-443c-819a2a54090dccec, 11
        /// </summary>
        static readonly PropertyKey TileDisplayName = new PropertyKey(TilePropertiesGroup, 11);

        /// <summary>
        /// 86d40b4d-9069-443c-819a2a54090dccec, 12
        /// </summary>
        static readonly PropertyKey TileImageLocation = new PropertyKey(TilePropertiesGroup, 12);

        /// <summary>
        /// 86d40b4d-9069-443c-819a2a54090dccec, 14
        /// </summary>
        static readonly PropertyKey TileUnknownFlags = new PropertyKey(TilePropertiesGroup, 14);

        /// <summary>
        /// 9f4c2855-9f79-4b39-a8d0e1d42de1d5f3
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly Guid MetadataGroup = new Guid(
            0x9f4c2855, 0x9f79, 0x4b39, 0xa8, 0xd0, 0xe1, 0xd4, 0x2d, 0xe1, 0xd5, 0xf3
            );

        /// <summary>
        /// 9f4c2855-9f79-4b39-a8d0e1d42de1d5f3, 5
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly PropertyKey AppUserModelID = new PropertyKey(MetadataGroup, 5);

        /// <summary>
        /// b6578b39-11f9-449b-8438cb5cf03b7d9c
        /// </summary>
        static readonly Guid UnknownGroup1 = new Guid(
            0xb6578b39, 0x11f9, 0x449b, 0x84, 0x38, 0xcb, 0x5c, 0xf0, 0x3b, 0x7d, 0x9c
            );

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a tile in the Windows 8 start screen.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="target">The file to be executed when the tile is clicked.</param>
        /// <param name="appId">The registering application's ID.</param>
        /// <param name="title">The caption text for the tile.</param>
        /// <param name="imageFilename">The image to be shown in the tile.</param>
        /// <param name="background">Background color for the tile.<para>
        /// Must be in the hex ARGB form: 0xAARRGGBB.
        /// Where AA is the alpha channel value, RR is for red, GG for green and BB for blue.
        /// </para></param>
        /// <param name="foreground">Foregreound color for the tile, in the
        /// same format as <paramref name="background"/>.</param>
        public static void CreateTile(
            string target,
            string appId,
            string title,
            string imageFilename,
            uint background,
            uint foreground
            )
        {
            string appdata = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            if (appdata == null)
                throw new NotSupportedException("The user's roaming application data directory does not exist.");

            using (var link = new ShellLink())
            {
                link.TargetPath = target;

                // The .lnk icon location and index (not quite important). Just using some defaults.
                link.SetIconLocation(@"%SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.DLL", 135);

                link.SetProperty(AppUserModelID, appId);

                // Apparently required properties (AS-IS).
                link.SetProperty(new PropertyKey(MetadataGroup, 11), true);
                link.SetProperty(new PropertyKey(MetadataGroup, 19), "Microsoft.InternetExplorer.Default");
                link.SetProperty(
                    new PropertyKey(MetadataGroup, 20),
                    "-contentTile -formatVersion 0x00000002 -securityFlags 0x00000000 -url 0x00000057"
                    );

                /**
                 * These are not really working at the moment; the tile just shows the name of the .lnk file.
                 */
                link.SetProperty(SystemItemTypeText, title);
                link.SetProperty(TileDisplayName, title);

                // Background and foreground.
                link.SetProperty(TileBackgroundColor, background);
                link.SetProperty(TileForegroundColor, foreground);

                // Small and normal tile icon. Set your own.
                string fileUri = new Uri(imageFilename).AbsoluteUri;
                link.SetProperty(TileImageLocation, fileUri);
                link.SetProperty(TileSmallImageLocation, fileUri);

                // Apparently required, not the tiniest clue of why.
                link.SetProperty(TileUnknownFlags, 0x41u);
                link.SetProperty(new PropertyKey(UnknownGroup1, 4), 0x41u);

                // The file should be saved to %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Application Shortcuts
                string filename = Path.Combine(appdata, @"Microsoft\Windows\Application Shortcuts");
                filename = Path.Combine(filename, "Win8Tiles-Test");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filename);

                filename = Path.Combine(filename, title + ".lnk");
                link.Save(filename);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Official Microsoft properties are documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd561977(v=vs.85).aspx one other source is the propkey.h file available in the Windows SDK. Example online here: http://code.google.com/p/audacity/source/browse/audacity-src/trunk/lib-src/portaudio-v19/src/hostapi/wasapi/mingw-include/propkey.h?r=10711  If you have a repro sample, we can try to help more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, @SimonMournier. I should have had mentioned in the question that I waded through (almost) the whole MSDN. I was also aware of the `propkey.h` header file, although I'm noticing substantial differences between the one that you are pointing out and the one from the SDK in my local drive. I made a mistake about the first GUID; I'm updating the question. I can't find anywhere on Earth (Internet) anything about these two sets so evidently related to Windows 8 tiles. I will try to share a repro.

Comment: @SimonMourier: I have added some repro code. The question is getting quite long, if there is need for more code just let me know. I would share a whole sample solution, but I don't see how (if it is possible) to attach a file to the question.

Comment: Can you provide also PropertyKey and ShellLink defines (you can use http://paste.bin)

Comment: @SimonMourier: There is nothing particularly interesting there, really. You can trust me. `PropertyKey` is a plain structure holding the `GUID` and the integer index passed through the constructor, as seen in the code. `ShellLink` just wraps the calls to the aforementioned **COM** interfaces. Simple straightforward code there. I'm totally positive the problem is not in that backing code, but in something that is missing in the properties being set in the shared `CreateTile(...)` method.

Comment: It's not we don't trust you, it's just less work for people who want to help you. Please consult this: http://sscce.org/ "It will, however, make people much more likely to help, and will therefore increase the chance of finding a solution."

Comment: I created link shell extension which adds new link file type in the system. When shell requests value of TileDisplayName key from my shell extension I return string "My Test App Tile" and I see this string in tile caption. So you are going on the right way but I don`t know why in your case TileDisplayName does not work. If you are interesting in I can publish all logs of communication between shell and my shell extension.

Comment: @SimonMourier: I'm checking with my employer the possibility to share more (hopefully the whole) code. Please, stay tuned. I have read at the link you provided. Are you suggesting I should strip the comments off the code, or just that I should share more code?

Comment: Just something that compiles :)

Comment: @DenisAnisimov: Thanks for your comment and your offer. It is an interesting approach, that about the shell extension. Those logs might be helpful, I don't mind wading through them. How can you share them? A link? Email?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Y6ZXBHcU

Comment: @DenisAnisimov: Solved it! Thanks a lot! Your log file was helpful indeed. Turns out that apparently I missed something obvious before. In the log, [`{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC}`, `10`] popped up immediately. Canonical name: `System.ItemNameDisplay`. That's the property I should have been using, instead of `System.ItemTypeText`. Don't know where I got that from. Anyway, thanks a lot. Out of curiosity: how was that log file generated? Where do those canonical names come from?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov: Even though you didn't answer the question directly, maybe you should add an answer to earn the rep points, because you actually provided the means to the decisive breakthrough. Just sayin'.

Comment: Log file was generated by my Shell Ace library. How to get canonical names you can find in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function GetPropertyKeyCanonicalName(const AKey: TPropertyKey): UnicodeString;
var
  PropertySystem: IPropertySystem;
  PropertyDescription: IPropertyDescription;
  N: PWideChar;
begin
  Result := '';
  if Succeeded(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_IPropertySystem, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IPropertySystem, PropertySystem)) then
    try
      if Succeeded(PropertySystem.GetPropertyDescription(AKey, IPropertyDescription, PropertyDescription)) then
        try
          if Succeeded(PropertyDescription.GetCanonicalName(N)) then
            try
              Result := N
            finally
              CoTaskMemFree(N);
            end;
        finally
          PropertyDescription := nil;
        end;
    finally
      PropertySystem := nil;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Delphi? Wasn't aware of the `IPropertySystem` interface, will definitely look into it. Thank you for your time.